# Text is not drawn over element with lower z-index

Tags: html, css

I have a hidden list on a page (`opacity:0;visibility:hidden;`) that is currently necessary for my menu.

My problem is that even though the z-index of the drop down part of the menu is -1 and the z-index of the content div is 50, the text inside of the content div only draws to the right of the menu. The css style `display:none` is not an option due to horrible resizing of elements that I don't want to deal with. Many Google and Stack Overflow searches produced no helpful results.

I have tried a variety of display settings including inline, `float:left`, and others that may have fixed the problem, but they didn't.

JSFiddle here which clearly defines the problem (try the second menu to see the cutoff point):
http://jsfiddle.net/nimsson/311g9h16/5/

I would like to know either

a) the reason behind this functionality

b) a workaround / solution

or both.

Thanks,

nimsson

Comment: I'd love to help you, but I'm having a little trouble figuring out what you want to know, or what you need help with. On your fiddle, it says "text that I want aligned left", but you talk about text drawing to the right, and the text I mentioned is centered in the page. Do you just want that text to be text-align: left?

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel I want the text to be drawn at the left margin of the div that it's contained in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply workaround You have here: http://jsfiddle.net/311g9h16/6/

I've just change `#content {position: absolute}` but why `display: none` is not an option?? Resizing should be no problem when You set height of dropdown.

Moreover, You can do this effect with some CSS - take a look: http://www.cssterm.com/css-menus/horizontal-css-menu/simple-drop-down-menu

Comment: The reason display:none is not an option is because there would be some unappealing resizing effects.

Comment: So another quick solution http://jsfiddle.net/311g9h16/8/ - of course there is some things to fix now, but what I've done 1/ float:left;clear:both on #content 2/ position absolute on dropdowns

Answer (score 1):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/311g9h16/7/ 
all I did was changing the way you use positioning and adjust the width to get the text to align left.

For info on position properties go here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

```
#content {
background-color: rgba(204,0,0,0.4);
border: 5px solid rgba(204,51,0,1);
border-radius: 10px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 500px;
color: white;
text-align: left;
width: 500px;
z-index: 50;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

}

Comment: I know that this wasn't specified in my question, but this example is not compatible with `width:100%`, which skews the div in weird ways.

Comment: I see. It looks like corn3lius just posted what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another div around the `#content` and re-set the page for the containing divs,

```
<div id="background"> 
....  </div>
```

css

```
#background{
  z-index:-1;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution where I only have to add an element.